# approximating $\#\{1 \leq x\leq j: \gcd (x,q)=1\}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $j \leq q$.

Is there a way to approximate $\#\{1 \leq x\leq j: \gcd(x,q)=1\}$?

We have

$\#\{1 \leq x\leq j: \gcd(x,q)=1\}= \#\{1 \leq x\leq q: \gcd(x,q)=1\}- \#\{j+1 \leq x\leq q: \gcd(x,q)=1\}= \phi(q)- \#\{j+1 \leq x\leq q: \gcd (x,q)=1\}$

Is there  way to formally show that since the multiples of $q$ are evenly distributed $[1,q]$, so

$\#\{j+1 \leq x\leq q: \gcd(x,q)=1\} \approx \phi(q) \frac{(q-j-1)}{q}$ (**)

If I could show this, then it would mean 
$\#\{1 \leq x\leq j: \gcd(x,q)=1\} \approx \phi(q) \left(\frac{q-(q-j-1)}{q} \right)= \phi(q) \frac{(j+1)}{q}$.

So, how do I show (**) formally? Also, is there a better way to approximate this?
Thanks.